# Is Cloudflare a good option in this case and if so, how set up it?

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare, video-hosting

I need to make a small (courses) platform where users aren't supposed to download the videos.

Is pass the media through CloudFlare a good way to prevent those downloads at least make harder? if not, what are others options that do you know?

I'm still figuring out CloudFlare... how should I set up it? from what I get, cloudflare doesn't store the contents itself, just act as intermediate to prevent ddos attacks, unathorized acess, etc but you're the one supposed to host the contents, so you just use your regular your web server for that. Is that right?

In case of #2 is correct, how am I supposed to set the DNS? in the domain's settings, set both cloudfare and my web hosting? or just set domain's DNS to cloudflare's? in that case, how do I set the host where the files will be stored? sorry, I'm very newbie about that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Only download videos, or do you also want to (live) stream? How download, viewing in a web player, or really download the files itself? And do you require encoding/transcoding, for example videos for mobile phone?

Comment: Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe the business problem you are working on, the research you have done, and the steps taken so far to solve it.

Comment: still offtopic. please read carefully [ask]